Как сделать переменную типа dropdown в скрипте Unity
Как сделать в скрипте Unity на c# переменную типа dropdown , то есть чтоб можно было указать в коде варианты, и в окне инспектора выбрать для этой переменной значение, одно из предложенных, помогите пожалуйста

Не переменную, а поле класса. Тип данных с фиксированными вариантами, называется enum.

Спасибо, бро, выручил
